# how to deal with imbalanced class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i have to make a classification of a dataset (*first order theorem*) with six classes and a not homogeneus distribution of values, as can be seen in the following list:

1. first class: 1089 data
2. second class: 486 data
3. third class: 748 data
4. fourth class: 617 data
5. fifth class: 624 data
6. sixth class: 2554 data

for a total of 6118 labeled datas for 51 all numerical features. there are a lot of feature highly correlated (there are 39 couples of feature with correlation higher than 0.75 or lower than -0.75); for this reason i tried a feature selection based on high correlation and also a PCA; the model i use is a svm optimized with grid search:

```
    svm = SVC(kernel='rbf', decision_function_shape='ovr')
param_grid = {'C': [50, 30, 100, 60, 25, 80],
              'gamma': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,0.001]}

grid = GridSearchCV(svm, param_grid, cv=10, scoring='f1_weighted',n_jobs=4,verbose=True)
grid.fit(all_train_data, train_target)
print(grid.best_params_)
```

and i used `F1_weighted` for the valutation of results. my question is: am i doing all right or there could be something missing that i could do related to the facts that the class are imbalanced (like parameter `class_weight` in svm)?

Answer (score 0):

till the difference between the most frequent class (sixth class) and least frequent one(second class) is 5 times bigger than the second class it might affect your classification a bit. there are a lot of approach to this type of problem you may use a Batch with the same amount of each class every time you train it or use data augmentation or any other methods

Comment: is class_weight a wrong approach for imbalanced classes?

Comment: it's one of the methods. honestly, I've never tried it!